# Get ID from database matching multiple names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database with columns

ID FirstName LastName. I would like get the id of various people. Hence I am writing queries like the below.

```
Select ID from Database where FirstName='X' and LastName='x1'
Select ID from Database where FirstName='Y' and LastName='y1'
Select ID from Database where FirstName='Z' and LastName='z1'
```

I there any way to optimize this query.

Comment: You've tagged your question with different RDBMSs. The answer might vary, which one are you actually using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put multiple condition in single where clause so just use them for simplicity.

```
Select ID from Database 
where (FirstName='X' and LastName='x1') OR 
      (FirstName='Y' and LastName='y1') OR
      (FirstName='Z' and LastName='z1')
```

with NULL Entries- You can add one more condition

```
  OR (FirstName is NULL AND LastName is NULL)
```

Comment: Sachin Thanks for the reply. Is there way to get even the Null values from this query. Means if Z and z1 records doesn't exist can I get the null value???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get row even for those name which are not exists in your `Database` table (don't use this name for your table, BTW):

```
select a.FirstName, a.LastName, d.id
from (
    select 'X', 'X1' union all
    select 'Y', 'Y1' union all
    select 'Z', 'Z1'
) as a(FirstName, LastName)
    left outer join Database as d on d.FirstName = a.FirstName and d.LastName = a.LastName
```